# Plain Object showing up in render using ocean modifer

Tags: rendering, modifiers, eevee-render-engine, ocean-simulation

[image: plain]

I'm testing this modifier and it turns out the plane I used to create the ocean always appears.

And yes, render option is activated.

[image: render option]

[image: render option2]

Comment: Are you sure that the Render option is enabled in the modifier?

Comment: yes, the render option is enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an object, that's hidden in viewport, but active on render

[image]

[Why does my object not show up?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up/67501#67501)